# Sleeper agent and Etrata the silencer

Tags: magic-the-gathering, mtg-commander

If I play [Sleeper Agent](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Sleeper%20Agent), my opponent gains control of it, and I exile it with a hit counter from [Etrata, the Silencer](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Etrata%2C%20the%20Silencer), would it count towards the creatures they own with hit counters?

Answer (score 5):

**No, Sleeper Agent does not count for Etrata, the Silencer.**

Etrata only counts cards *owned by your opponent* that it exiled. Sleeper Agent was controlled by your opponent, but you are its owner at all times. It does not matter who controlled the creature on the battlefield when it was exiled.

> 108.3. The owner of a card in the game is the player who started the game with it in their deck. [..]

Fun fact: If your opponent also had their own Etrata, your Sleeper Agent would even count for their Entrata, turning him into a real double agent!

Comment: "Fun fact: If your opponent also had their own Etrata, your Sleeper Agent would even count for their Entrata" Although if this was the third creature that you owned that was exiled, you wouldn't lose until another creature was exiled.